# When defining a rule via the Grakn Java API, I get an error when I try and exclude uniary relations

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

```
type("overlap-rule").sub(Graql.Token.Type.RULE)
            .`when`(
                and(
                    `var`("t1").isa("trip"),
                    `var`("t2").isa("trip"),
                    `var`("t1").neq(`var`("t2"))
                )
            ).then(
                `var`().isa("trip-overlap")
                    .rel("overlapped-trip", "t1")
                    .rel("overlapped-trip", "t2")

            )
```

Gives an error:

```
match $o isa trip-overlap; get;
Error: UNKNOWN: Invalid state in variable predicate [[$t1 !== $t2]] with answer [[$t1/V4136][$t2/V4136]]: either a concept is missing or not an attribute.. Please check server logs for the stack trace.
```

But when trying to define the same rule in graql, everything works:

```
overlap-rule sub rule,
    when {
        $t1 isa trip;
        $t2 isa trip;
        $t1 != $t2;
    }, then{
        (overlapped-trip: $t1, overlapped-trip: $t2) isa trip-overlap;
    };
```

```
ekg> match $o isa trip-overlap; get;
{$o id V81928216 (overlapped-trip: id V4136, overlapped-trip: id V4296) isa trip-overlap;}
```

Does neq not work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two kinds of "not equals" in Graql! There is the `!=` that you used in the graql rule definition, which states that two *concepts* cannot be the same.

There is another type of not equals, that is written `!==` in the language itself, representing the comparison of attribute concept values!

The trick is that `!==` is written using `var1.neq(var2)` in the Java query builder, whereas `!=` is written using `var1.not(var2)` in the query builder ;)

Comment: Thank you - what was the reason for the change of syntax? Or rather what was the reason for using ```var1.`not`(var2)```?

Comment: It's hard to say when it arose, but the two syntax's exist for different reasons: `!=` is used for checking two concepts are not identical, useful for finding two role players that aren't the same for instance. `!==` is most useful for comparing attribute values across different types, which would always be false if compared with `!=`